# python 3 how to avoid print a newline after "."

Tags: string, variables, python-3.x, printing, newline

I have this code:

```
f=open('myfile.txt','r')
name=[]
for line in f:
    name.append(line)
for i in range (len(name)):
    print("hola"+name[i]+".txt".format((name[i]).strip("\r\n")))
```

myfile has two rows separated by newline, like this:

```
Da
Df
```

And I would like this ouput:

```
holaDa.txt
holaDf.txt
```

But instead, I have this:

```
holaD4I5M4
.txt
holaD4i5J8.txt
```

And I tryed several things to avoid the newline before the ".", but nothing seems to work. 
Thank for your help! I am very new in Python, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're stripping the string correctly, but instead of outputting the stripped value, you're outputting the original value. Using using `"hola{0}.txt"` format instead of outputting the original value with `"hola"+name[i]+".txt"` will output the correct - stripped - string;

```
for i in range (len(name)):
    print("hola{0}.txt".format((name[i]).strip("\r\n")))
```